# In ETW, how to enable ProcessRundown events for Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process?

Tags: etw

Provider's manifest indicates that it can send `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process::ProcessRundown::Info` events, which I'd really like to have: they give a summary of processes that existed at the time the trace has started.

For reference, in the "usual" process provider enabled by `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_PROCESS`, rundown is sent automatically via `MSNT_SystemTrace::Process::DCStart` events. However, data fields in that provider does not allow to find the process's image path: `ImageFileName` field is an ANSI filename without a path, and `CommandLine` field is also unreliable, because it could contain relative path (in worst case, no path at all). For this reason, I need `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process` provider.

Answer (score 2):

After quite a lot of trying, I found a very simple way: after the provider is enabled with `EnableTraceEx2(EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_ENABLE_PROVIDER)`, an additional `EnableTraceEx2(EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE)` will send the events.

Eventually, I enable provider this way:

```
    namespace Microsoft_Windows_Kernel_Process
    {
        struct __declspec(uuid("{22FB2CD6-0E7B-422B-A0C7-2FAD1FD0E716}")) GUID_STRUCT;
        static const auto GUID = __uuidof(GUID_STRUCT);

        enum class Keyword : u64
        {
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_PROCESS                  = 0x10,
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_THREAD                   = 0x20,
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_IMAGE                    = 0x40,
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_CPU_PRIORITY             = 0x80,
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_OTHER_PRIORITY           = 0x100,
            WINEVENT_KEYWORD_PROCESS_FREEZE           = 0x200,
            Microsoft_Windows_Kernel_Process_Analytic = 0x8000000000000000,
        };
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////

    const u64 matchAnyKeyword =
        (u64)Microsoft_Windows_Kernel_Process::Keyword::WINEVENT_KEYWORD_PROCESS;

    const ULONG status = EnableTraceEx2(
        m_SessionHandle,
        &Microsoft_Windows_Kernel_Process::GUID,
        EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_ENABLE_PROVIDER,
        TRACE_LEVEL_VERBOSE,
        matchAnyKeyword,                        // Filter events to specific keyword
        0,                                      // No 'MatchAllKeyword' mask
        INFINITE,                               // Synchronous operation
        nullptr                                 // The trace parameters used to enable the provider
    );

    ENSURE_OR_CRASH(ERROR_SUCCESS == status);
```

And request rundown like this

```
    const ULONG status = EnableTraceEx2(
        m_SessionHandle,
        &Microsoft_Windows_Kernel_Process::GUID,
        EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE,       // Request 'ProcessRundown' events
        TRACE_LEVEL_NONE,                       // Probably ignored for 'EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE'
        0,                                      // Probably ignored for 'EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE'
        0,                                      // Probably ignored for 'EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE'
        INFINITE,                               // Synchronous operation
        nullptr                                 // Probably ignored for 'EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE'
    );

    ENSURE_OR_CRASH(ERROR_SUCCESS == status);
```

Comment: Which provider did you use to capture the process rundown? SystemProcessProviderGuid?

Comment: No, the question is about `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process`. Updated answer to include some code.

Comment: Again, as described in the question, `EVENT_TRACE_FLAG_PROCESS` can also be used to get rundown, but the information in the events is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to get rundown events in a circular in memory / file buffer trace, but it seems to only work for tracing a sequential file. I've been using the SystemProcessProviderGuid however since I also need the CPU profiling events.

Comment: Post a separate question about it and I will answer how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, posted here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73494012/how-to-get-rundown-events-with-circular-buffer-tracing-with-etw