# How to get rundown events with circular buffer tracing with ETW

Tags: windows, etw

I have been trying to use ETW for always on profiling within my app, by using the circular buffer tracing mode. Specifically CPU profiler events for the entire system, using the kernel mode event tracing session.

It seems that process rundown events are not captured unless sequential buffering mode is used. This means that WPA does not know the process names for the processes which it has captured, making it unable to provide any useful information.

Is there any way to get these rundown events in a circular buffer tracing session?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the following code works:

```
namespace SystemTraceControl
{
    struct __declspec(uuid("{9e814aad-3204-11d2-9a82-006008a86939}")) GUID_STRUCT;
    static const auto GUID = __uuidof(GUID_STRUCT);

    enum class Keyword : u64 {
        RUNDOWN_DCSTART = 0x01,     // No idea what the real name is
        RUNDOWN_DCEND   = 0x02,     // No idea what the real name is
    };
}

<...>

const u64 matchAnyKeyword =
    a_IsStart ? (u64)SystemTraceControl::Keyword::RUNDOWN_DCSTART
              : (u64)SystemTraceControl::Keyword::RUNDOWN_DCEND;

// See MDSN for 'EVENT_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR' near 'EVENT_FILTER_TYPE_TRACEHANDLE'
EVENT_FILTER_DESCRIPTOR filterDesc;
filterDesc.Ptr          = (ULONGLONG)&m_SessionHandle;
filterDesc.Size         = sizeof(m_SessionHandle);
filterDesc.Type         = EVENT_FILTER_TYPE_TRACEHANDLE;

ENABLE_TRACE_PARAMETERS params;
ZeroMemory(&params, sizeof(params));
params.Version          = ENABLE_TRACE_PARAMETERS_VERSION_2;
params.EnableProperty   = EVENT_ENABLE_PROPERTY_STACK_TRACE;
params.EnableFilterDesc = &filterDesc;
params.FilterDescCount  = 1;

const ULONG status = EnableTraceEx2(
    m_SessionHandle,
    &SystemTraceControl::GUID,
    EVENT_CONTROL_CODE_CAPTURE_STATE,   // Sends rundown when used together with 'EVENT_FILTER_TYPE_TRACEHANDLE'
    0,                                  // Provider seems to ignore it
    matchAnyKeyword,                    // Has special meaning when requesting rundown
    0,                                  // Provider seems to ignore it
    INFINITE,                           // Synchronous operation
    &params                             // Used to give 'EVENT_FILTER_TYPE_TRACEHANDLE'
);
```

Note that it doesn't make much sense to request start rundown, because due to the nature of circular buffer, it's likely to get overwritten soon. Instead, request end rundown when finalizing your session to disk.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!